# Where should I direct this question about SEO on a website that isn’t mine?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

The question was as follows:

> **What is the purpose of these low DA, high number of outbound linking sites?**
>
> I've noticed a particular website getting a lot of backlinks from .tk,
>   .gq and other cheap or free domain sites. They are all designed with
>   the same stock bootstrap theme, and every site is exactly the same in
>   terms of structure and function. They seem to all be image directories
>   where the images are linked to (with a 'dofollow' link).
>
> They have other interesting and sketchy features, such as white text
>   on white backgrounds to stuff keywords within the anchor text.
>
> Here is an example of one of the homepages on these sites:
>
> [image]
>
> [image]
>
> What's going on here? I understand that it's a scraper or some
>   automated system, but I don't understand why. Is there a particular
>   SEO benefit for anyone in the chain?
>
> Has anyone seen anything like this before and, if so, what was it all
>   about?

I initially posted it to [Webmasters Stack Exchange](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/), but they don’t allow you to post about other peoples’ websites in [their rules](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

I then posted it to [Web Applications](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/), here: [What is the purpose of these low DA, high number of outbound linking sites?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/119676/what-is-the-purpose-of-these-low-da-high-number-of-outbound-linking-sites)

And they recommended I post here. Where should I direct this question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There doesn't look like it has a home anywhere on Stack Exchange. As it's about SEO, Webmaster's is the closest fit, but since they don't want it, you're probably out of luck.

Fortunately, there are any number of online forums that discuss SEO, and not all of them deal in snake oil. I'm sure you can find one or three where this question would be welcome.

Comment: Thanks, I thought this might be the answer. I'll have a look at this option.

Comment: http://searchengineland.com might be a good option.